# what do I need to do on a unix machine to allow some PC computer to mount (NFS)

Tags: unix, mount, nfs

I have a unix computer and a PC computer.

I want to mount a drive in the PC onto a unix directory.

What do I need to do in the unix side to allow this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be NFS specifically, or just any network filesystem? Also, what *exactly* do you mean by "PC computer", and what's the difference between "PC computer" and "Unix machine" anyway? (Most Unix derivatives *do* run primarily on "PC"s.)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean a PC running windows, and you already have done the proper means to set up NFS and exported the directory you want to share, you

- Install the NFS client for windows, in Win-7 you go to Add/Remove programs and 
  Turn Windows features on or off

[image]

Enable the NFS Client

[image]

- Mount the share. Go to the start menu. righ click Computer and chose Map network Drive

[image]

Enter the share name on the form host:/share , e.g.

[image]

(Note that the windows nfs client doesn't support NFSv4)

Answer (score 1):

I assume by PC you mean a computer that is running a flavor of Windows...  If this is the case, you need to "share" this drive on the network on your Windows PC, setup a workgroup, and give the drive a shared name.

Then, you need to [install a Samba client](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/install.html) on the Unix machine.  [Samba](http://samba.org/) is the protocol most commonly used for Unix computers to mount shared Windows network drives.  If you provide some more information on the two PCs, I could provide more detail.

Comment: No. I mean the other way around. Unix is the NFS servers.

Comment: I know that I can use "net use" on the unix, but I get a 53 error. What steps should I use on the unix? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, then it is still Samba, but you need to setup a Samba server on the Unix machine, then if done correctly, will appear as any other windows shared network drive for you to connect to in your 'Network Places' on your windows machine.

Comment: If you provide your Unix OS, I can provide a link to help, or you can just Google "Configure Samba Server {your_unix_os_here}"